# Zoom camera in/out with Mouse Scrollwheel via the transform instead of fov?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseOrbit : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 5.0f;
    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

    public float yMinLimit = -20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

    public float distanceMin = .5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;

    float minFov = 15f;
    float maxFov = 90f;
    float sensitivity = 10f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        x = angles.y;
        y = angles.x;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Updating camera distance on every frame
        distance = RayCast3.distance3;

        //Setting maximum distance so the camera doesnt go too far
        if (distance > 2)
        {
            distance = 2;
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (target)
        {
            x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
            y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

            y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);

            //distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);
            //distance += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * sensitivity;
            float fov = Camera.main.fieldOfView;
            fov += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * sensitivity;
            fov = Mathf.Clamp(fov, minFov, maxFov);
            Camera.main.fieldOfView = fov;

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
            {
                distance -= hit.distance;
            }
            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
            Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;

            transform.rotation = rotation;
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F)
            angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F)
            angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

Now i'm using fov:
And it's working fine.

```
float fov = Camera.main.fieldOfView;
fov += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * sensitivity;
fov = Mathf.Clamp(fov, minFov, maxFov);
Camera.main.fieldOfView = fov;
```

But now i want to use the distance variable and not fov. 
So i tried first the line:

```
distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);
```

It didn't work so i tried the line:

```
distance += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * sensitivity;
```

But in both lines the character is stuttering and it's not zooming in out with the mouse wheel.

Comment: in ClampAngle => should be `if (angle >= 360F)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really simple. Get mouse scroll wheel speed then multiply it by some speed value. You can also multiply it by `Time.deltaTime` if you want. Finally use `transform.Translate` to move the camera with that value.

This will move in z-axis:

```
private float zoomSpeed = 2.0f;

void Update()
{

    float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * zoomSpeed, Space.World);
}
```

Or where camera is facing:

```
private float zoomSpeed = 5.0f;

void Update()
{

    float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    transform.position += this.transform.forward * scroll * zoomSpeed;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but scroll value is all the time 0. I used Debug.Log(scroll); after the line float scroll...and it's 0 all the time.

Comment: Sorry, this is not true on my side. It was tested properly and I use it in one of my games. You likely messed with your InputManager settings  and messed up  "Mouse ScrollWheel".  Go to Edit-->Project Settings-->Input then reset it.

Comment: Working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate a delta between your camera point and your target point. Normalize it and multiply it with the scrollwheel delta. Add this on your camera position. I used the camera target as angle to zoom-in.

*Pseudo:*

```
var delta = cameraTarget - cameraPosition;
delta.Normalize();
cameraPosition += delta * ScrollWheel.delta * sensitivity;
// you can even move your cameraTarget in the same direction
cameraTarget += delta * ScrollWheel.delta * sensitivity;
```

You can use the `distance` instead of calculating a delta.